# How exactly is RMSE computed in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The rmse computed by tensorflow does not match with the rmse computed manually by me. The relevant code has been pasted below :

```py
# Train a linear regression model.
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
OUTDIR = 'sample_model_metadata'
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(OUTDIR, ignore_errors=True)
model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=make_feature_cols(), model_dir=OUTDIR)
model.train(make_train_input_fn(train_data, num_epochs=1))

#Make predictions on the validation data set.
predictions_vals = np.zeros(len(validation_data))
predictions = model.predict(input_fn = make_train_input_fn(validation_data, 1))
i =0 
for items in predictions:
  predictions_vals[i] = items['predictions'][0]
  i += 1


evaluated_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(predictions_vals, validation_data['Y']))
print(evaluated_rmse)

def print_rmse(model, df):
  metrics = model.evaluate(input_fn = make_train_input_fn(df, 1))
  print('RMSE on dataset = {}'.format(np.sqrt(metrics['average_loss'])))

print_rmse(model, validation_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my input function, which was  having shuffling turned on by default, causing the validation data to get jumbled and hence resulting in an erroneous validation score.

```
def make_train_input_fn(df, num_epochs=1, shuffle=True):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=df,
        y=df['Y'],
        batch_size=128,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        queue_capacity=2000)
```

I have made sure that shuffling is turned off while doing validation and this has fixed the issue.

```
predictions = model.predict(input_fn = make_train_input_fn(validation_data, 1, False))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0 
for items in predictions:
  predictions_vals[i] = items['predictions'][0]
```

You are saving all the `predictions` into the same location of np array `predictions_vals` i.e. at  `i = 0`. You missing `i += 1` here ! unless you copied the code wrongly here.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I had corrected the code now. However, that still does not look to solve the original problem. There still looks to be a mismatch !